# Domain Driven Design: "If E exists do A, otherwise do B" logic belongs to application service or domain service?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Say I want to take different actions based on whether a specific entity exists, like:

```
item := itemRepository.Find(id)
if item != nil {
    item.Description = newItem.Description
    ...  // More actions
    itemRepository.Save(item)
} else {
    ...  // More actions
    itemRepository.Save(newItem)
}
```

I believe this piece of code should either belong to an application service or a domain service, but can't really decide which is the right one. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Isin't that logic just `createOrUpdate(newItem)`? In this case it shall be handled by the repository IMO and most ORMs would do that for free.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, really.  Logic that depends on the state of the domain belongs in the domain model.

```
item = items.Find(id)
item.doTheCleverThing(newItem)
items.Save(item)
```

The branching logic you have here belongs in the repository.

```
Find (Id id) {
    state = database.Fetch(id)
    if (null == state) {
        return factory.defaultItemWithId(id)
    } else {
        return factory.item(state)
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: this is *not* obvious from reading the original text in Evans.  His chapter on life cycles really doesn't explain creation patterns very well, and his descriptions of repositories are really thin.